# Azure b2c throwing undefined error which is vague error and should be user/email exists error?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

[image]

this undefined error is thrown by Azure B2C when i try to signup an existing user can i fix this issue somhow?

Comment: We are having the same error, did you resolve this?  it's returning JSON but the UI shows undefined, happens both in a default or custom template:

{"status":"400","errorCode":"ViralErrorUserCreationConflict","message":"A user with the specified ID already exists. Please choose a different one."}

Comment: still facing this issue maybe some one from microsoft will fix it soon

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have a few bug reports into them myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with selfasserted version 2.1.19.
See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1154586/azure-b2c-gives-undefined-as-the-error-message-whe
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout#self-asserted-page-selfasserted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

## Workaround

To workaround this issue and display the correct error message, you can do the following:

1. If you haven't already, follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to add a custom HTML template for the page.
2. If you haven't already, follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to enable JavaScript in your custom template.
3. In the B2C authentication screens, open the browser dev tools and reproduce the error that causes "undefined" to be displayed. Then, locate the last network request and inspect the response JSON, noting the `errorCode` and `message` properties.
   [image: Browser dev tools, showing a network response JSON.]
4. Add the following script to the bottom of your custom HTML template (inside the `<body>` tag), replacing the error code and message with the one from your devtools. If you like, you can also customise the error message.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
if (CONTENT) {
  CONTENT['UserAccountNotFound'] = CONTENT['UserAccountNotFound'] ?? 'A user with the specified credential could not be found.'
}
</script>
```

5. Upload the updated HTML template, and the correct error message should not be displayed.

## Explanation

It seems that `undefined` is being displayed due to Microsoft having a bug in the page's JavaScript. The variable `u` is initially set to the correct message, while `f` is set to the string `'undefined'` as the `errorCode` is not found in the page's lookup dictionary. Then the next line contains `u = f` which results in the string `'undefined'` being printed as the error.
[image: JavaScript with Microsoft's bug]

To workaround this, we need `lookupLanguage` to return the correct string. To do this, we need to add items to the page's lookup dictionary, which helpfully is a global variable named `CONTENT` that can be easily modified in a custom script.

In the future, Microsoft will hopefully fix this bug so that the workaround will no longer be needed.