# Undefined error shown to user when using already registered email in azure b2c user flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using azure b2c for registration on my website. I have configured user flows for sign up and sign in the journey, it is working fine but when the user tries to register with an already registered email, he is getting error message "undefined", rather than showing user-friendly message

I tried looking at azure docs and portal but couldn't find anything useful. I am expecting appropriate error messages to be shown in case of any issue during the registration journey using user flow.

I am sending error message in structure mentioned by azure in below doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-user-flow#example-of-a-validation-error-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD B2C user flow:

[image]

When I run the user flow, I signed up with the user like below:

[image]

The user got signed in successfully like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: As per [MSQnA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1154586/azure-b2c-gives-undefined-as-the-error-message-whe) by *James Hamil*, the deployment to fix the issue has been hot fixed to display the error.

**When I tried to sign up with the same user, I got the error like below:**

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, try the workaround mentioned in this [**StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74610899/azure-b2c-throwing-undefined-error-which-is-vague-error-and-should-be-user-email) by Daniel Elkington.

- Otherwise try using 2.1.9 version to display the error.

Comment: The workaround is more focused towards custom policy and i want to use user flows. It's working with your suggestion on using 2.1.9. Do you know if Microsoft is planning to fix this issue in latest version? Looking at the comment from below link, this should have been fixed in early Feb this year.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1154586/azure-b2c-gives-undefined-as-the-error-message-whe

Comment: AFAIK it is not fixed yet

Comment: So the workaround will be configuring custom policy or using version 2.1.9.